# How to leverage plpgsql with my postgresql statements

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I have the following **postgresql** statements:

CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW X....
;

ALTER TABLE X...
;

CREATE INDEX A...
;

CREATE INDEX B...
;

Currently I run each statement one after to other to get to the desired result, how I can use **plpgsql** to only have to run the statement once and eliminate steps? I am new to plpgsql and a basic intro would be greatly appreciated.
Note, the **plpgsql** extension is already installed.

Comment: No. Besides indexes for constraints (UNIQUE, PRIMARY KEY, FOREIGN KEY) postgresql does not support inline index definitions.

Comment: If you are new to Postgres, *why* do you think you want a materialized view? This sounds like an XY-problem...

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve here? An atomic execution of all statements? That can be done by simply putting them into a transaction.

Comment: @wildplasser I have 8 views, each performing calculations on anywhere between 17k and 200k records, merging into one. Therefore I am merging all the views into a materialized view for performance purpose when querying the view. If you know of a better solution don't hesitate to let me know